# AngularJS: How can I create a custom filter that can convert the numbers of a string to h:m format?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, oop, filter

I am loading a JSON list of movies into the scope and each movie has a duration. JSON snippet:

```
"duration": "PT157M"
```

This duration is displayed as a string where the number is the duration in min. How can I convert the number into the format "h:m". ex: 150 = "2:30" so that this is in the View?

I tried using javascript with dummy data (to see if it works), but I assume a custom filter is smarter?

```
.controller('MovieController', ['$scope', 'MovieFactory',  
   function($scope, MovieFactory) {

MovieFactory.get().then(function(response) {

  $scope.movies = response.data;

  // extract numbers from string
  $scope.duration = 'PT150M';
  $scope.regex = /\d+/g;
  $scope.found = $scope.duration.match($scope.regex);
  console.log($scope.found);

  // convert number to hours:min
  function timeConvert(n) {
    $scope.num = n;
    $scope.hours = ($scope.num / 60);
    $scope.rhours = Math.floor($scope.hours);
    $scope.minutes = ($scope.hours - $scope.rhours) * 60;
    $scope.rminutes = Math.round($scope.minutes);
    return $scope.finalResult = $scope.num + " min = " + $scope.rhours + " hour(s) and " + $scope.rminutes + " minute(s).";
  }
  console.log(timeConvert($scope.found));

});

}]);
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
 <p>Duration must be here: {{movie.duration}} </p> 
</div>
```

I've read a lot of documentation, sadly without any luck.

Comment: Show the custom filter code that you tried. Start with the example in the docs. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters). Or start with this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/wCQQdldqKXkjvKX02kfD?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.duration.match($scope.regex);` returns the matched numbers as an array with one element (a string of "150" in this case).

You want something like this instead: `parseInt($scope.duration.match($scope.regex)[0]);`